# Problem connecting with Beagleboard through serial?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnu-screen

I'm trying to connect to a BeagleBoard on Ubuntu using a Serial-to-USB adapter. It is currently being recognized as ttyUSB0 on our system. When I run "screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200" the output just says "Screen is Terminating" and returns us back. When I try using sudo in front of this command, it'll recognize the Beagleboard as the root but the output is all over the place and gives us a variety of characters on the screen.

[image]

is there anything that can be done to fix this issue we're having? I've tried connecting through PuTTy as well but I am an error connecting as well.

Comment: It seems like your flow control settings might be wrong.

Comment: Might want to try `minicom`. It'll let you fiddle with the parity and stop bit settings. It looks like `\033` is getting garbled.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me in similar situation is removing the **modemmanager** package from Ubuntu 15.10, as [discussed here](https://askubuntu.com/a/155376/525025).

```
sudo apt-get remove modemmanager
```

Followed by a  reboot.  Now I could connect with

```
sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

To avoid using `sudo`, you must be in the *dialout* group to which the `/dev/tty` files belong. I've added myself to the group

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

And rebooted the system. Now I am able to connect with simple

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

After connecting, the terminal window is blank and I have to press Enter to see the login prompt:

[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Usually garbled text means that your speed/parity/stopbit settings are wrong. I'd always try 9600 baud first and then go up one step at a time with default settings for the other values.